# What is the fastest algorithm for division of crazy large integers?

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming

I need to divide numbers represented as digits in byte arrays with non standard amount of bytes. It maybe 5 bytes or 1 GB or more. Division should be done with numbers represented as byte arrays, without any conversions to numbers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Large-integer_methods

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your assistance

Comment: One valuable resource about arithmetic with large numbers is the [GNU
Multiple Precision
Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/manual/Division-Algorithms#index-Division-algorithms) and its manual.

Comment: @greybeard Thank you for providing this useful information.